# Orientation change in Presented View Controller not updating Parent View Controller

Tags: ios, ipad, orientation, ios-autolayout

So I am working on porting my iPhone only app to support iPad as well (universal) but I am having trouble with orientation changes on iPad.

What is happening is when I present a modal view controller from a parent view controller that is in, say Portrait orientation, and then the orientation changes to landscape in the modal, and then the modal is dismissed, the parent view controller's views are incorrectly sized. The parent view's subviews are controlled by auto layout constraints, so I have tried to force them to update on dismissal of the modal view, but haven't had any luck.

The parent's views support both Portrait and Landscape properly (i.e. when the user rotates the device when in the parent view), this only occurs when a modal's orientation changes.

I've attached some screenshots that hopefully will help explain what I am trying to explain.

Thanks to all in advance.

[image: Parent View Controller (Portrait)]

[image: Modal View Controller (Portrait)]

[image: Modal View Controller (Landscape)]

[image: Return to parent view controller (Landscape)]

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I've found that this was because of the [RZTransitions](https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZTransitions) library. I've created an issue on that project [here](https://github.com/Raizlabs/RZTransitions/issues/52).